# value of $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^r{n\choose k}{n-2k\choose r-k}}{\sum_{k=r}^n {n\choose k}{2k\choose 2r} {(\frac{3}{4})}^{(n-k)}({\frac{1}{2}})^{2k-2r}}$ .

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation

The question requires us to find the value of $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^r{n\choose k}{n-2k\choose r-k}}{\sum_{k=r}^n 
  {n\choose k}{2k\choose 2r} {\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}^{(n-k)}\left({\frac{1}{2}}\right)^{2k-2r}}$ . $(n≥2r)$
I tried using a couple of ways to proceed but couldn't simplify the expression, then I tried checking by putting arbitrary values of $r$ and $n$, but the answer seems to come different for different values of r and n , so does this expression not have a constant value or am I wrong somewhere? If there is some way to solve this, a little hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit the question in the title and the post to be same?

Comment: @bigbang yes, sorry